# Wordpress theme not displaying when activated on production server, but will display on development environment

Tags: wordpress, themes

Wordpress theme not displaying when activated on production server, but will display on development environment. I can view the theme in preview mode, but not when it's activated. Any idea on where to start would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you are using something like [wp-cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cache/) or [wp-supercache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/)?  When you change themes you'll want to disable all caching.  Change the theme and verify the change.  Then re-enable caching.

Answer (score 0):

What displays? Another theme? Un-styled HTML? Nothing?

If you could provide a little more information it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is being displayed, I have noticed that the theme you are trying to use may be missing a file for whatever reason. If this is the case, switch back to the Default theme and make sure all of the files for the new theme are installed.